# URL to open Google doc in “Suggesting” Mode

Tags: google-docs

Is there a URL convention that allows me to share a Google doc so that when it is opened it is in “Suggesting” Mode but still allows the user to change to “Edit” Mode?

I know that I can share a document with COMMENT privileges which locks users into a “Suggesting” mode, But I want my users to be forced to think about changing OUT of “Suggesting” mode and still be able to switch TO “Edit” mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is exactly what I wanted. The ability to share a doc, but only share it with SUGGEST mode instead of full edit mode.

Thank you Google.

Comment: The thing is that one may want to share a link to a document where people can do suggestions / comment and optionally change to edit mode to fix/add stuff. Aka explicitly do edits, not by accident

Comment: Also, this option should say "Anyone with the link can comment and suggest edits". It's not clear from that text that it allows suggesting edits. One might expect better UX from Google, oh well.

Comment: I just noticed that this only works with native Google docs. If you're sharing a .docx, it instead provides a drive.google.com link which opens in a Google Drive view similar to if it was a PDF, and you can only add comments but not suggest edits. There are two solutions: 1) to make a copy as a native Google doc, share that, and probably ditch the .docx, or 2) change the URL to this format: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/<LONG ID HERE>/edit?usp=sharing`.

Answer (score 5):

A document will only open in Suggesting or View mode when it has been shared with a collaborator using those permissions. If you are the owner of the document, or if you are a collaborator with Edit permissions then you will need to manually change those settings each time you open the document.

Comment: Is there no way to programmatically change this mode? I would MORE than happily add a single line of code onOpen(e) for each doc setting the mode to Suggesting. It should an option you can set for ALL docs...

Comment: @fionaredmond is there any way to change a shared document url to open in viewing mode and the user manually change to suggesting mode instead of the opposite? Seems people are damaging document by mistake, causing administrative burden (havin to reject proposed changes that were done by mistake)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis you can add `/preview` at the end of the document's URL. I wonder if there is such a mode for suggesting. I understood it was the purpose of this thread...

Comment: Oddly, `/comment` works too, but doesn't seem to have any effect.  `/otherstuff` gives an error.